# Configure embedded tomcat server to only listen to localhost connections

Tags: java, localhost, ip-address, hostname, tomcat9

I am running an application with an embedded tomcat server which by default listens to any connections (binds to 0.0.0.0). I am trying to bind the server to listen to localhost connections only. How can I achieve this within my launcher class? (without using any special configuration files)

```
        tomcat.setPort(8080);
        tomcat.setHostname("localhost");
        ...(adding webapp and servlet)...
        tomcat.start();
        tomcat.getServer().await();
```

Comment: I don't have the answer, but with config files this is done on the Connector. See if you can access it programmatically.

Comment: Yup, I did some tracing in the code and noticed that the address to bind to seems to be defaulted in the connector, but so far I haven't found any option to set this programatically through the Tomcat instance. One potential option I found was to manually build the connector and call setConnector on the Tomcat instance. However, I was hoping for a more trivial solution if anyone faced this problem in the past.